# HasMany relation combining with other HasMany that excludes previous

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-7, has-many

Is there a way in Laravel to define a relationship that hasMany relations to one but the ids do not appear in another hasMany relation?

For example,

properties

| id | name | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |

vehicle_to_properties

| id | property_id | vehicle_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

additional_manufacturer_properties

| id | property_id | manufacturer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

exclude_manufacturer_properties

| id | property_id | manufacturer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

A parent vehicle class got `properties`, that can be extended by the manufacturer or can be excluded. So that a `SpecificCar` hasMany `additional_manufacturer_properties` and hasMany `exclude_manufacturer_properties`.

So `SpecificCar` inhibits `properties` from `vehicle`, gets additional `properties` from `additional_manufacturer_properties` and some properties get excluded by `exclude_manufacturer_properties`.

I want to know all `properties` that the `SpecificCar` got. I would like to display this by a relation, that the `SpecificCar` hasMany properties, with all from the parent class, with all additional, but without the excluding ones.

What I have right now is a collection of attributes, where I reject all ids that are in the excluding table:

```
$properties->reject(fn ($e) => in_array($e->id, $exclude))
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: your question is not clear to me. I assume you have defined different relations in your model for additional and excluding right? and when you are loading your SpecificCar model you can use either one relation to get your desired properties. 

What is the issue you are looking for ?

Comment: @fahim152 thanks I try to elaborate my question a bit

Comment: sure, it would be helpful for others to understand more clearly then

Comment: Can you do it at the database level? The performance gains could be useful.

Comment: Database changes are unfortunately not an option.